# GAE - Starting dynamic backends from queues

Tags: google-app-engine, queue, backend

I'm attempting to run a GAE queue using a dynamic backend:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
queue.add(TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/parse").method(Method.GET).header("Host",
BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("backend1", 1)));
```

backends.xml

```
 <backends>
     <backend name="backend1">
          <class>B2</class>
          <instances>1</instances>
          <options>
              <dynamic>true</dynamic>
          </options>
     </backend>
  </backends>
```

Does this automatically start the backend?  I don't think it does.  How do you start the dynamic backend?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes it should start a backend - dynamic backends are started on first http request. Why do you believe it's not starting a backend?

Comment: if I run /parse independently it works (using frontend) but when I run /queue to execute the code above nothing happens.  I think I get an Http 404 error

Comment: the queue runs but /parse doesn't execute

Comment: Can you invoke the backend by hand? https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/backends/overview#Addressing_Backends